# arcpy.da.Walk can not get feature class in dataset with Chinese in path (could reoccurrence bug)

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, feature-dataset, walk

2023.02.27 edit. I know how fix it now, but would like to know why so that I can change my module.

I used to use this function to iterate all feature classes, but it has a problem with path with Chinese.

I guess it needs encoding or decoding instruction but don't know how.

```
def iterate_feature(workspace):
    walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass")
    return [os.path.join(dirpath, filename) for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk for filename in filenames]
```

```
def debug(in_gdb):
    for i in iterate_feature(in_gdb):
        arcpy.AddMessage(i)
```

Example1: with this gdb file it will list all features sucessfully.

```
in_gdb = C:\test.gdb
----setA
--------feature1
----setB
--------feature2
----feature3

# output
# C:\test.gdb\feature3
# C:\test.gdb\setA\feature1
# C:\test.gdb\setB\feature2
```

Example2: same gdb copied from example1, but in path with Chinese.

```
in_gdb = C:\中文\test.gdb
----setA
--------feature1
----setB
--------feature2
----feature3

# output
# C:\中文\test.gdb\feature3
```

When the output of example2 shows up, **I find 2 empty files created in test.gdb (check with file explorer) named "setA" and "setB". And now even move test.gdb back to whole English path it will only output feature3**

***Delete files "setA" and "setB", move back to whole english path can make function work again.***

Other examples for your reference

Example3: same gdb but dataset name with Chinese. ("setA中文" will be created)

```
in_gdb = C:\test.gdb
----setA中文
--------feature1
----setB
--------feature2
----feature3

# output
# C:\test.gdb\feature3
# C:\test.gdb\setB\feature2
```

Example4: English path, but feature name with Chinese.

```
in_gdb = C:\test.gdb
----setA
--------feature1中文
----setB
--------feature2
----feature3中文

# output
# C:\test.gdb\feature3中文
# C:\test.gdb\setA\feature1中文
# C:\test.gdb\setB\feature2
```

What I have tried at 2023.02.26:

If I run`iterate_feature(r'C:\test.gdb')`, I will only get one output `C:\test.gdb\feature3`. Where did feature1 and feature2 go?

I have tried `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(r'C:\test.gdb')` and `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(r'C:\test.gdb\setA')`. None of them could get me feature1 and feature2.

Describe() has been tried too.

```
for child in arcpy.Describe(r'C:\test.gdb').children:
    arcpy.AddMessage(child)
```

Only feature3 shows up.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. The logical question to ask about sudden behavior changes is: What else changed on the system? File system corruption? Corrupted software install? There's too many variables for us to tell you what's wrong with your system.

Comment: @Vince That's the confusing point. I have 2 desktop computer and 1 laptop. All of them are win10, with same edition of arcmap10.8, vscode, python 2.7, and I didn't change anything really. This happened on 2 desktop computer and I will try it on laptop tomorrow.

Comment: FYI, your function worked for me and I have 10.7

Comment: Sounds like filesystem corruption to me. Check the file count within the .gdb folder.